# Some columns are not populated on the database when saving using doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I had a doctrine entity and I added two new properties (msoId and contract). Now when the code to persist the entity is executed, the 2 new columns are saved with NULL value, no the ones that I am passing on the set(). The columns that already existed are working fine. I have to point out that it works fine in my local computer, but it is not on TEST and STAGE environments. I already regenerated the proxies with "doctrine orm:generate-proxies", but the issue continues. It looks like some kind of caching, but I do not know. Please help.

**Entity:**

class SubscriptionSettlement extends Entity {

```
const COMPLETE = 1;
const INCOMPLETE = 0;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11, nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="entitlement_id", type="integer", nullable=false, length=11, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $entitlementId;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="due_date", type="integer", nullable=false, length=11, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $dueDate;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="package_id", type="integer", nullable=false, length=11, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $packageId;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="complete", type="boolean", nullable=false, length=1, options={"unsigned"=true, "default"=0})
 */
private $complete;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mso_id", type="integer", nullable=false, length=11, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $msoId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $contract;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getEntitlementId(): int
{
    return $this->entitlementId;
}

/**
 * @param int $entitlementId
 */
public function setEntitlementId(int $entitlementId)
{
    $this->entitlementId = $entitlementId;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getDueDate(): int
{
    return $this->dueDate;
}

/**
 * @param int $dueDate
 */
public function setDueDate(int $dueDate)
{
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getPackageId(): int
{
    return $this->packageId;
}

/**
 * @param int $packageId
 */
public function setPackageId(int $packageId)
{
    $this->packageId = $packageId;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getComplete(): int
{
    return $this->complete;
}

/**
 * @param int $complete
 */
public function setComplete(int $complete)
{
    $this->complete = $complete;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getMsoId(): int
{
    return $this->msoId;
}

/**
 * @param int $msoId
 */
public function setMsoId(int $msoId)
{
    $this->msoId = $msoId;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getContract(): string
{
    return $this->contract;
}

/**
 * @param string $contract
 */
public function setContract(string $contract)
{
    $this->contract = $contract;
}
```

}

**Code that save into the database:**

```html
$subscriptionSettlementEntity = new   SubscriptionSettlement();
        $subscriptionSettlementEntity->setEntitlementId($entitlementId);
        $subscriptionSettlementEntity->setDueDate($dueDate);
        $subscriptionSettlementEntity->setPackageId($packageId);
        $subscriptionSettlementEntity->setComplete($complete);
        $subscriptionSettlementEntity->setMsoId($msoId);
        $subscriptionSettlementEntity->setContract($contract);

        try {
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($subscriptionSettlementEntity);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $ucve) {
            throw new DatabaseException(
                "This subscription has already been renewed",
                DatabaseException::UNIQUE_INDEX_VIOLATION_CODE
            );
        }

        return $subscriptionSettlementEntity->getId();
    }
```

Comment: Clear metadata cache

Comment: That was the issue. I just ran the command "doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata" and it is working fine now. Thank you!